# Why is this function throwing a 'strict' error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I want to have a function that is called from when the page loads, this function will then add listeners to a div tag on the page, the listeners will change a global variable in my javascript file to either true or false, but I can't do this as I get an error about the function being strict when I attempt to do it.

Browser: Chrome

Error:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

View Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".cut-images");
    [].forEach.call(imgs, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, false);
        img.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd, false);
    });
});
```

Javascript:

```
    var isOnDiv = false;

function dragStart(e) {
    this.style.opacity = "0.4";

        document.getElementById("chuckImage").addEventListener("mouseenter", function () { isOnDiv = true; });
        document.getElementById("chuckImage").addEventListener("mouseout", function () { isOnDiv = false; });



    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}

    function dragEnd(e) {

        if (isOnDiv === true)
            alert("ding");
        this.style.opacity = "1.0";
    }
```

Does anyone know why my function might be throwing this error?

Comment: Which browser? If not chrome / firefox than probably calling a property on an undefined object will be ignored in non-strict mode.

Comment: Happening in Chrome

Comment: Maybe it's the same source as for this [known issue](https://www.telerik.com/forums/known-issues-and-important-changes#KKI7NGE4P0K-jwQGL525dA): _"If you get errors like **access to strict mode caller function is censored** especially under Firefox, the solution is to downgrade to jQuery 1.11.1 that the suite used before."_

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I would like to avoid changing versions for the sake of one function.

Answer (score 0):

In your js file there is used some lines like below globally

```
 'use strict';
```

due to this reason something violated as per strict mode and raised error.

you can see more details [here...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strict-mode-javascript/)